# Erro ocorre ao realizar a injeção de recurso no Bean

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Bean:

```
package br.com.drogaria.bean;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import br.com.drogaria.dao.FabricanteDAO;
import br.com.drogaria.domain.Fabricante;

@ManagedBean(name = "MBfabricantes")
@ViewScoped
public class FabricanteBean {
    private ListDataModel<Fabricante> fResultSearch;
    public ListDataModel<Fabricante> getfResultSearch() {
        return fResultSearch;
    }
    public void setfResultSearch(ListDataModel<Fabricante> fResultSearch) {
        this.fResultSearch = fResultSearch;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void catalogo() {
        FabricanteDAO fdao = new FabricanteDAO();

        try {
            ArrayList<Fabricante> list = fdao.listarTudo();
            fResultSearch = new ListDataModel<Fabricante>(list);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Página:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/template/modeloSistema.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="menu">
        <ui:include src="/includes/menuPrincipal.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nada encontrado :("
            value="#{MBfabricantes.fResultSearch}" var="item">

            <p:column headerText="Código">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.codigo}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Descrição">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.descricao}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado MBfabricantes
>       javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Poste o stacktrace completo, deve ter ocorrido algum erro no `PostConstruct`. E troque a `SQLException` por uma exceção mais genérica, só para verificar o stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

A resolução disso foi:

Na fabrica de conexões, especificamente no método,
coloquei o seguinte comando (apesar da minha versão do Java ser a 7):

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
```

Answer (score 1):

Um adicional para sua própia resposta (Isto deveria ser um comentário, mas estranhamente em algumas perguntas estou impedido de comentar (sou usuário novo)).

Você fazer DriverManager.registerDriver(Driver driver) pode ser redundante. O que estava ocorrendo é que o DriverManager da sua aplicação não estava sendo notificada para registrar o driver. Veja o trecho de [inicialização static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) da classe com.mysql.jdbc.Driver:

```
    //
    // Register ourselves with the DriverManager
    //
    static {
        try {
            java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
        } catch (SQLException E) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
        }
    }
```

Não que isto seja importante, mas é a maneira como os Drivers JDBC funcionam (eles só precisam ser acionados uma vez para serem registrados automaticamente). Para evitar um acoplamento forte direto da sua classe com o driver, opte por fazer

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Geralmente em um servidor de aplicação, esse trecho de código não é requerido.